# How do I add gestureHandling: 'cooperative' to gmaps for rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

How do I add `gestureHandling: 'cooperative'` to the map using [gmaps for rails](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the [JS Methods section of the docs](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Js-Methods)?

Something like this should work:

```
var handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
handler.buildMap({
    internal: { id: 'map' },
    provider: {
      gestureHandling: 'cooperative'
    }
  },
  function(){ }
);
```

Comment: Will give you bounty as soon as SO allows. Thanks!